# Angular2 Service Subscribe not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I cannot store data into UserDetailsArr object , PFB code for your reference.

User Details Class:

```
    export class UserDetails
    {
        userId:string;
        userName:string;
        password:string;
        firstName:string;
        lastName:string;
        mobileNumber:string;
        email:string
    }
```

Service Class:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core'
    import {OnInit} from '@angular/core'
    import {UserService} from './user.service'
    import {User} from './user'
    import {UserDetails} from './user'
    import {UserDetailComponent} from './user-detail.component'
    import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

    @Component(
        {
            selector:'user-list',
            template: `
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <div>
                <table border='1'> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name </th>
                        <th>Last Name </th>
                        <th>Mobile Number </th>
                        <th>Email </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                      <tr *ngFor="let user of UserDetailsArr">
                        <td> <span (click)="showDetails(user)"> {{user.firstName}} </span> </td>
                        <td> {{user.lastName}} </td>
                        <td> {{user.mobileNumber }} </td>
                        <td> {{user.email}} </td>
                    </tr>                      
                </table>
                </div>
                <user-detail *ngIf = "selectedUser != null" [user] = "selectedUser"></user-detail>
                <br/><br/><br/>

            `, 
            providers:[UserService , HTTP_PROVIDERS],
            directives:[UserDetailComponent] 
        }
    )   
    export class UserListComponent implements OnInit
    {
        users:User[];
        UserDetailsArr: UserDetails[]= [];
        errorMessage: string = '';
        isLoading: boolean = true;
        public selectedUser = null;
        constructor(private _userService:UserService)
        {

        }

        ngOnInit():any
        {
            this.getUsers();
        }

        getUsers()
        {

             this._userService.getUsers()
                   .subscribe(
                        /* happy path */ p => this.UserDetailsArr = p,
                         /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
                         /* onComplete */ () => this.isLoading = false);                  


           console.log(this.UserDetailsArr);
        }

        showDetails(user)
        {
            this.selectedUser = user;
        }



    }
```

web Service is working perfecltly If I log like below,

```
   this._userService.getUsers()
           .subscribe(
                /* happy path */ p => console.log(JSON.stringify(p),
                 /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
                 /* onComplete */ () => this.isLoading = false));
```

user data has logged in browser console.

```
    [{"UserId":"bcb444aa-401b-48a7-b1bf-17b4bf78b834","UserName":"prabhu","Password":"pwd","FirstName":"PRABHU","LastName":"ARUMUGAM","MobileNumber":"1234567890","Email":"prabhu@gmail.com"},
    {"UserId":"d9e5ba40-d0d7-4d90-89b0-7e26660cc84b","UserName":"senthil","Password":"pwd","FirstName":"SENTHIL","LastName":"KUMAR","MobileNumber":"1234567890","Email":"senthil@gmail.com"},
    {"UserId":"a59dabad-5a8c-4ced-9006-2181bf8c10cb","UserName":"vijay","Password":"pwd","FirstName":"VIJAY","LastName":"RAJ","MobileNumber":"1234567890","Email":"vijay@gmail.com"},
    {"UserId":"f3e2d351-9413-4d80-8623-36556d27f875","UserName":"thamizh","Password":"pwd","FirstName":"THAMIZH","LastName":"VANAN","MobileNumber":"1234567890","Email":"thamizh@gmail.com"}] 
    (e) { return _this.errorMessage = e; } () { return _this.isLoading = false; }
```

But if I assign the data to UserDetailsArr data is not assigned,

```
     this._userService.getUsers()
           .subscribe(
                /* happy path */ p => this.UserDetailsArr = p,
                 /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
                 /* onComplete */ () => this.isLoading = false);  
   console.log(this.UserDetailsArr);
```

Next line I tried to print but its not working, result is undefined.

Comment: Well, of course. Your service is asynchronous. That's why it returns an Observable, and not just an array of users. So the function `p => this.UserDetailsArr = p` is executed long after the line `console.log(this.UserDetailsArr);`, when the users are available, most probably when you get the response to the HTTP request used to get the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observables call the callbacks passed to `subscribe(...)` or other operators like `map(...)` when data arrives.

The code after `subscribe(...)` is called immediately afterwards and as @JbNizet mentioned this is usually long before data arrives.

You need to move code that depends on the data received from the observable into one of the callbacks like:

```
 this._userService.getUsers()
       .subscribe(
            /* happy path */ p => {
                this.UserDetailsArr = p;
                console.log(this.UserDetailsArr);
            },
             /* error path */ e => this.errorMessage = e,
             /* onComplete */ () => this.isLoading = false
       );
```

Comment: Seems there is missing something after `but`?

Comment: yes, :-)  But i need to loop through UserDetailsArr object and bind data in *ngFor Directive, I edited service class above now, Its not working Im getting empty table result.. Can u plz help?

Comment: You might need to add `json()` like `p => this.UserDetailsArr = p.json()`. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: getUsers() 
    {
    let people$ = this._http.get(this.getUserUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
       return people$;
    }                   this is _userService getUsers Method. In user listCOmponent im getting p.json is not a function error

Comment: `this._http.get(...)` returns a `Subscription`. You can't return the value from a call to `this._http.get(...)`. You only can assign the value somewhere when the code passed to `subscribe(...)` or `map(...)` is called.

Comment: Hi, I am having almost the same problem, but in your example, line 6, you close the subscription brackets, which means that the onError and onCompleted is now outside of subscription, and thus I get an error `unexpected token` at what would be your last line...

Comment: I don't think so. The closing curly closes the first callback `p => { ... }`

Comment: Yes, but the bracket after the closing curly closes the .subscribe, and is the `e=>` and the `()=>` not part of the .subscribe? (Just asking, it is the error I am getting)

Comment: :) So where I have a problem is if I change the last line to `() => console.log('done')`, it will not log out the "done". Do I understand it correctly form the manuals that the `.subscribe` will only do the onComplete when it is finished, so I do not know why it is not executing the line. And there is no error, my onError line is `err => console.error(err),`, and this does not log anything as well...

Comment: Perhaps the observable is never closed. Try `someService.getObservable().first().subscribe(...)`, then the `onComplete` callback has to be called after the first event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136142/discussion-between-alfa-bravo-and-gunter-zochbauer).